# Partition one array into three array

Tags: arrays, vector, matrix, sequential

I try to split array that contain sequential value like, array_source = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} into three array A, B, C.

First iteration of array_source will inserting the current array_source value into array A, the second iteration of array_source will inserting the current array_source value into array B, the third iteration of array_source will inserting the current array_source value into array C, and so on.

so the result will be look like below,

```
array_source = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

array A = {0,3,6,9}
array B = {1,4,7}
array C = {2,5,8}
```

thanks in advance,
idunk
P.S array value may increasing dynamically i.e 0-100 , 0-1000

Comment: C++? Java? Ruby? PHP? Python? Scala? Objective-C? Lua? C#? VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

In C#

```
int counter = 0;
foreach(int i in array_source)
{
if(counter == 1)
{
// Add to array 1
counter++;
}
else if (counter == 2)
{
//Add to array 2
counter++;
}
else if (counter == 3)
{
// Add to array 3
counter = 1;
}
}
```

This is a very basic and probably not too efficient way of doing this (also completely untested), im guessing this is homework?

Comment: @Idunk which language are you writing this in?